# Invite Friend in Google Play Services

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-play-games

I'm creating a Game App in objective-c which is using Google Play Game services for realtime Multiplayer functionality. I follows the documentation at https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer. In my app there are two options Auto match and Invite Match. Auto Match functionality working fine. But Invite match not.
I follow following Code for this

```
- (int)minPlayersForPlayerPickerLauncher {
    return 1;
}

- (int)maxPlayersForPlayerPickerLauncher {
    return 2;
}
- (IBAction)inviteFriendsWasPressed:(id)sender
{

    // This can be a 2-4 player game
    [GPGLauncherController sharedInstance].playerPickerLauncherDelegate = self;
    // This assumes your class has been declared a GPGPlayerPickerLauncherDelegate
    [[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentPlayerPicker];
}
```

on click this button Action follow Screen is open
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwNbD.png)

After that when I enter emailId in textfield there is no action perform to search particular user.

Please help me
 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,  the player selection no longer works since Google+ is no longer integrated into Play Game Services: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html

Comment: But in the documentation at https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer, we can invite the players.

Answer (score -1):

```
// request code for the "select players" UI
// can be any number as long as it's unique
final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;

// launch the player selection screen
// minimum: 1 other player; maximum: 3 other players
Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 3);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }

        // get the invitee list
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        final ArrayList<String> invitees =
            data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

        // get auto-match criteria
        Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
        int minAutoMatchPlayers =
            data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
            data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

        if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
            autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                    minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
        } else {
            autoMatchCriteria = null;
        }

        // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
        RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
        roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
        if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
            roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
        }
        RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);

        // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}

// create a RoomConfigBuilder that's appropriate for your implementation
private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder(this)
        .setMessageReceivedListener(this)
        .setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
}
```